# Convert from http to https (http://localhost:4200 to https://localhost:4200<or secured port>)

Tags: angular, https

I want to make my localhost of angular client secure
i.e. want to update local url from "http://localhost:4200/" to "https://localhost:"

Any idea how can we do that

Comment: If you want to use https in prod only you can use the `import {isDevMode } from '@angular/core'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular CLI can serve via HTTPS, but you need to explicitly configure it to do so.
First, you need a certificate and key. A self-signed certificate is sufficient for local development and has the advantage that you can put the private key in your project repo, too.

You should create key and certificate with `openssl` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/9032927

Next step is to tell Angular CLI to use the certificate and key to serve via HTTPS:

```sh
ng serve --ssl --ssl-key path/to/my/ssl.key  --ssl-cert path/to/my/ssl.crt
```

Please also consult the Angular docs for all possible `ng serve` options: https://angular.io/cli/serve